# Closed form solution for Mean-Variance optimization without short-selling

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

So I am writing my bachelor thesis about the naive portfolio vs mean-variance portfolio and I am currently a bit stuck at the part about describing the mean-variance portfolio. I know that if there are only constraints in the form of equalities, you can use the Lagrangian method in order to find a closed form solution for the problem:
$$
min\frac{\lambda}{2}w\Sigma w^T-w^T\mu 
$$
But in my problem I have the following constraints:
$e^Tw=1$ and $0\leq w_i\leq1$, with e being the vectors of ones.
Can I only find a optimal weight allocation by using quadratic programming?

Comment: Because of the no short selling constraint the answer is unfortunately yes, there is no analytic solution for this case. It requires applying an optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed-form solution for this in DeMiguel, Plyakha, Uppal, Vilkov (2013) in equation (8). You can take a look at it yourself in the paper as well. However, this is only for the minimum-variance portfolio, I am not sure if there is one for the mean-variance. For this minimum-variance case,

\begin{equation}
w_{min} = \frac{\Sigma^{-1} e}{e^T \Sigma^{-1} e}
\end{equation}

with $e=[1, 1, \cdots, 1]$. The only difference being that you can short securities, so you no longer have the purely positive weights constraints. However, I am more of a fan of the quadratic programming approach. Hopefully this gives you some ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was indeed already moving towards quadratic programming but I thought maybe a closed form solution would be easier.

Comment: @soulsbornefan you can give me an upvote if you feel my answer helped :)

Comment: @Kai I think he was asking explicitly for a solution with shortsale constraints..I was thinking about something similar to Kuhn-Tucker, however, this leaves the question unsanswered as one has to specify the Lagrange multipliers ..